# Linux find object for glxext.h functions -> cannot find correct .so -> "undefined reference"

Tags: c++, opengl

My application is using functions found in glxext.h (ex /usr/include/GL/glxext.h), however it seems I'm not linking with the correct library.

Which library/compilation unit contains the matching functionality?

I'm already linking with the following libraries:

```
-lopengl -lcuda -lcudart -lGL -lglut -lGLEW -lGLU -lX11 -lXNVCtrl -lXxf86vm -lXi -lXmu -lXext
```

Output

```
undefined reference to `glXEnumerateVideoCaptureDevicesNV'
undefined reference to `glXLockVideoCaptureDeviceNV'
undefined reference to `glXBindVideoCaptureDeviceNV'
```

I'm supposing it might just be a matter of finding the correct lib to link with. I found LWJGL which might contain the right components.

Answer (score 2):

This functions are part of [GLX_NV_video_capture](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/video_capture.txt) GLX extension. If you attempt to link with them and getting reports that this functions not found in `-lGL`, it is most likely means your GLX don't have this extension. You can verify that with `glxinfo|grep NV_video_capture` command.

Since extension could be missing, it is generally recommended to first query supported extensions with `glXQueryExtensionsString` (which will return space-separated list of supported GLX extensions) and then, if extension you need is supported, use `glXGetProcAddress` to get pointer to each function you need. If you'll link with extension function statically, your program wouldn't be able to run on any other implementation that don't have this extension.

Comment: It isn't an issue at all. Some implementations (rather a combination of driver and graphics hardware) supports some extensions, others does not - that's exactly why it is called extension. For example my work computer with intel graphics doesn't have NV_video_capture, while home desktop with nvidia graphics does.

Comment: The way I see it is that even though my current development machine does not have the required hardware&driver I would like it to be able to setup a build for the deployment machines that do have driver & hardware that make use of such extensions... Hence all I'm simply asking for is a development library (in this case you hint that it's a different libGL.so library) that contains this functionality, even if I can't actually execute certain portions of the application.

Comment: continued: Given your input, can I assume that the libGL.so that is required would come with a driver update for "the correct" graphics card? In my case that would be graphics drivers for an Nvidia quadro graphics card (i'm currently developing on a Geforce)."NV_video_capture, while home desktop with nvidia graphics does. " - Well I'm only working on desktop machines with discrete nvidia graphics and I then appear not to have it.

Comment: This is exactly why you need to use `glXGetProcAddress` at runtime rather than linking directly. While latest nvidia drivers should have this functions even if no capture hardware present, it isn't a requirement, and others (e.g. AMD) may not have it.

Comment: It does appear that I do have the library in one of my GL.so libs though: jimmy@jimmy-minipc:/$ sudo find -name *GL.so* | xargs nm -D | grep glXEnum
0000000000080240 T glXEnumerateVideoCaptureDevicesNV .......

Comment: It is `libGL.so.1`, as I've told initially (`-lGL` asks linker to link with `libGL.so`, which points to `libGL.so.1`). Everything else was me saying that you don't want to do that :-)

Answer (score 0):

After some very helpful input from keltar i started investigating why my GL.so did not contain the correct functionality.

Indeed it should be in most modern GL.so for nvidia machines(from NVIDIA 190.XX drivers @ 2011 and forward), so it really should be on my machine (modern desktop with GTX980).

Running:

```
jimmy@jimmy-minipc:/$ sudo find -name libGL.so | xargs nm -D | grep glXEnum
0000000000080240 T glXEnumerateVideoCaptureDevicesNV
0000000000080e60 T glXEnumerateVideoDevicesNV
0006d910 T glXEnumerateVideoCaptureDevicesNV
0006e180 T glXEnumerateVideoDevicesNV
00044f89 T glXEnumerateVideoCaptureDevicesNV
00045a89 T glXEnumerateVideoDevicesNV
```

Helped me realize that I do indeed have the needed functions. These were located in

/usr/lib/nvidia-343/libGL.so
instead of
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so

Note that nvidia-343 comes from the most recent driver update on my machine.

While keltar's getProcAddress solution would be perhaps more correct in an unknown deployment environment I doesn't quite suite my needs as it would require large code rewrites and furthermore I have quite controlled deployment environment.